# exporting IK rig into another software

Tags: rigging, export, game-engine

dear blender users.

I have researched about ways to export an IK rig from blender into another software, especially unreal engine, but I haven't found any way.is there really any way to export an IK rig into the unreal engine or any other software from blender? please notice, I mean rig, not animation

Comment: IK rigs are software specific. You cannot transfer it since other software uses other IK solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you want to perform animation in Blender, then export the rigged and animated character, the solution is to bake the animation on the deforming bones, so to freeze the Ik calculations, and export the simplified version (with no IK constaints).

If you want to animate in UE, you have to export a rig without IK constraints but with all IK controller bones, then reconstruct the IK functionality using UE blueprint IK system (or directly with code).